# Java Spring web app file upload with relative path

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, path

I am working in a web app build with Java, Spring and Hibernate.
I want to code a file upload so users can upload photos, but I can´t solve an issue with relative paths.
Here you can see the code of the spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView subidaFicheroUnico(@RequestParam("fichero") MultipartFile fichero, @ModelAttribute("maquinaSeleccionada")Maquina oMaquinaSeleccionada) throws IOException {

     File imagenUpload = new ClassPathResource("imagenes/maquinas/fullsize").getFile(); 
     
     
     String CARPETA_IMAGENES = imagenUpload.toString();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("subidaFicheros");
    
    if (fichero.isEmpty()) {           
        mv.addObject("mensaje", "Seleccione una imagen");
    }

    try {

        /** Guardar el archivo en disco */
        byte[] bytes = fichero.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(CARPETA_IMAGENES +"/"+ fichero.getOriginalFilename());
        Path path2 = Paths.get(imagenUpload.toURI());
        String routePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(File.separator).getPath();
        
        Files.write(path, bytes);
        
        /** Guardar el archivo en BD */            
        Imagen oNuevaImagen = new Imagen (  oMaquinaSeleccionada.getIdMaquina(),
                                            fichero.getName());
        servicioImagen.insertaImagen(oNuevaImagen);
        
        mv.addObject("mensaje", "Ha subido correctamente la imagen '" + fichero.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
        
        logger.info("Fichero subido:"+path.toString());
        logger.info("Fichero subido:"+path.toFile().toURL().getPath());
        logger.info("Fichero subido:"+path.toUri().getPath());
        logger.info("Fichero subido:"+path.toString());
        logger.info("Fichero subido:"+path.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
    
    return mv;     
}
```

I have found a way to handle relative paths with ClassPathResource:

```
File imagenUpload = new ClassPathResource("imagenes/maquinas/fullsize").getFile();
```

Here you can see a working example of a file with the image directory path.
The problem is that you can't create a ClassPathResource with the path of a file which doesn't exist. I only can create one with the directory and when I add the file name, the file isn't uploaded to the directory.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? You want to upload the file relative to what?

Comment: The problem is that I want to save the new file in a directory inside my project (resources/imagenes/maquinas/fullsize) and I don´t know why but it isn´t uploading the file. I think it is a problem of the relative path.

Comment: There is no project at runtime, you don't run source code. Hint: the problem isn't relative path, it's more basic.

Comment: How can I solve this?I mean how can I upload a file in the resources folder inside my project?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ServletContext.getRealPath, check the document [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

ALL you need is to autowire ServletContext bean

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

then you can use servletContext.getRealPath to get the path of a directory under webapps appending to it the name of the new created file, so suppose you have folder under webapps named images

```
String pathStr= servletContext.getRealPath("/images")+"new name";
```

then get the by stream of your multipart object

```
byte[] bytes = fichero.getBytes();
```

Then use Files utility to write the file

```
Files.write(Paths.get(pathStr), bytes);
```

Comment: It still doesn´t work. The path seems to be ok, but no file is created in the path.

Comment: @Pedro you are on windows or linux?

Comment: Windows. The resulting path is E:\Eclipse\Workspaces\wks_LaPoderosa2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\GestionMaquinaria\resources\img\maquinas\fullsize\DSCN1072.JPG . This path is a temp path created when you run the app,isn´t it?The real directory is in ...wks_LaPoderosa2\GestionMaquinaria\...

Comment: try this String pathStr= servletContext.getRealPath("/images/")+"new name";

Comment: The path doesn´t seem to be valid. Error java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: E:\Eclipse\Workspaces\wks_LaPoderosa2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\GestionMaquinaria\img\DSCN1072.JPG. The only valid path is the one I posted before.

Comment: The problem is that this path is used when the app is running. When you close it, no file is saved. I don´t know how save it on the real path.

Comment: to save it on the path you only need to read the byte stream of the file and write it as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes, I know how this works, if you see the code at the start of the post, I have done that. The problem is getting the path. If I use the absolute path of the folder in my computer (E:/Eclipse/workspaces/.....)it works ok, but when I try to use relative paths, it doesn´t works at all. The path I have with your method seems to be a temp path used in running time. When you close the app, the file isn´t there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152962/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-pedro).

Answer (score 0):

Finally the answer of Amed Qarabsa was right:

```
String pathStr= servletContext.getRealPath("/images")+"new name";
```

But it only works in production, I mean an external server. On eclipse server doen´t work.